# Where is Web Site Administration Tool in Visual Studio 2013 And Above

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2013 and above Microsoft has removed "ASP.NET Configuration" option from Project Menu.

Where is this option?

> Picture of Visual Studio 2012

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Download "ASP.NET Configuration.zip" form this link:

> [Download "ASP.NET Configuration.zip"](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4ovljdj79aam1yi/ASP.NET+Configuration.zip)

Then extract it and copy "ASP.NET Configuration.bat" to project folder and run it.

browser will open with this:

> Picture of "Web Site Administration Tool"

[image]